# Link fills full width of a sidebar in angularmaterial

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sidebar, angular-material

I'm trying to reproduce the sidebar of https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/.
I take a bit of code from the HTML source. The problem I have is that links (used as buttons) do not take the full width (FOOBAR is hovered):

[image]

When I hover the angularmaterial's website sidebar, the link takes the full width of the navbar (Autocomplete is hovered) :

[image]

Here is the code I use :

```
<div ng-controller="SidebarCtrl" layout="column" flex>
  <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')" flex>
    <ul class="side-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="item in menu">
        <a class="md-button" ng-class="{'active' : isSelected()}">
          <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            {{item.label}}
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

I use no custom-css (only the one provided by material-design).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of setting your's anchor's CSS to be `display: block` and `width: 100%`.

Here's a sample:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

li a {
    width: 100%;
    background: #106CC8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff
}
```

Then you just have to get the font and spacing correct.

Here's a JSFiddle to get your started: http://jsfiddle.net/u03znojv/2/